# React Native, Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I'm trying to run my react app in my physical device with `react-native run-android` it's showing error in terminal that `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function` I used debug it showed error occurred in `node-modules/react-native/libraries/core/ExceptionsManager.js` I tried to fix the error and deleted my node modules file and re-install it with `npm install` but still getting same error

My debug console

[image]

error I'm getting and app just hanged in welcome image

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to render an object somewhere in your component?

Comment: no,  I don't thing so

Comment: are you using constructor anywhere in the code ?

Comment: Hye @GuruparanGiritharan it's me kanwar, ah don't know may be not actually it's not my code my sir give this app and code to me to analyze it but it's not working, it's just showing that error

Comment: just check for constructor or super in the code n see

Comment: ok wait it will check it

Comment: oh ya there is two

Comment: inside constructor check whether you return super(props)?

Comment: yup there is super(props)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223549/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-dark-prince).